# Why do we need Comet or HTTP polling when we aren't using a browser?

Tags: web-services, comet

If you have total control of both ends of the wire (client and server), why do people suggest using Comet or HTTP long polling? I understand when you only have a browser as it can only communicate over HTTP.

People say you need to do this to beat firewalls because port 80 will be open. But why not just communicate directly over port 80 without using HTTP? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes an HTTP proxy will be running on port 80. This will only permit HTTP traffic and block/discard FTP or other TCP traffic.

Update: A proxy is a server between a client and server. It can appear to be almost transparent to the casual user, but on closer inspection of traffic you can find evidence of it. There are different types of proxy which can handle different types of traffic. HTTP proxies are popular for anonimization of traffic, control of HTTP access on corporate networks, and to improve performance through caching.

Comment: What is an HTTP proxy? It redirects port 80 traffic to other servers by protocol? So if it isn't HTTP then it will throw it on the floor?

Comment: Also where might this proxy live that it will introduce this problem? If it isn't on the server side.

Comment: It will live between the user's desk and the Internet.  Your question presupposes you control both the client and server.  Do you also (and will you always) control the stuff in between?

Comment: +1, it's all about keeping expected information on expected ports. It can also be firewalls - some firewalls inspect the data coming across specific ports to see if any of it could be malicious. Non-http data would almost certainly be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of firewall or proxy your organization uses. 
A proxy will usually be pretty strict about http only traffic through it, and can easily block anything that is not truly http traffic. This includes looking at the http headers etc to make sure they are present and valid.

If you don't have a proxy buy just a firewall at your organization, it may let you pass anything through port 80, but even these devices are becoming more intelligent these days and can act more like a proxy by inspecting your connection data and validate it against a set of rules.